# Unable to start docker container with systemd when SELinux is in enforcing state

Tags: systemd, selinux

When I start the Docker container which has systemd in it, with SELinux in `enforcing` state, I get an error message "No such file or directory" and the container does not start.

Audit logs give the below error messages:

> avc:  denied  { read execute } for  pid=XXXX comm="w" path="/w/w" dev="sda3" ino=135817694 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c712,c950 tcontext=system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c373,c565 tclass=file permissive=0
>
> avc:  denied  { read execute } for  pid=XXXX comm="sh" path="/usr/bin/bash" dev="sda3" ino=2687570 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c337,c629 tcontext=system_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

I added below SELInux policies to fix it:

```
allow container_t default_t:file { create execute execute_no_trans ioctl open read write };
allow container_t container_file_t:file { execute execute_no_trans read write };
allow container_t default_t:dir { add_name remove_name write };
```

But I still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Docker have own startup method. Launch with option '--restart=always'

[docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)